# How to change supportVersion project property in nativescript Android platform?

Tags: gradle, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Anybody knows how to change android supportVersion project property as well as android build tool version for a nativescript project?

Answer (score 0):

Open the `<project-folder>/app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle` file and add the following snippet:

```
dependencies {
     compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.1+"
}
```

You can adjust the support version as it suits your case.